# Search WordPress Archive by title and/or taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have an archive with a list of researchers, I would like to be able to filter them via form by either name and/or organization(taxonomy). Currently, I am able to search either or, but not both. For example if my dropdown menu has organizations A, B and C, and I have researchers David (A), Sally (B), Jon (B).

I search David - I get the result, David.
I search Organization B - I get the result, Sally and Jon.
I search David and Organization B - I get a 404 page instead of no results found or David, Sally and Jon.

```
function add_query_vars_filter($vars)
{
  // add custom query vars that will be public
  // https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars
  $vars[] .= "organization";
  $vars[] .= "r_name";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter("query_vars", "add_query_vars_filter");

/**
 * Override researcher Archive Query
 * https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts
 */
function researcher_archive($query)
{
  // only run this query if we're on the researcher archive page and not on the admin side
  if (
    $query->is_archive("researcher") &&
    $query->is_main_query() &&
    !is_admin()
  ) {
    // get query vars from url.
    // https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var#Examples

    // example.com/researcher/?rating=4
    $category = get_query_var("organization", false);
    $name = get_query_var("r_name", false);

    // used to conditionally build the meta_query
    // the meta_query is used for searching against custom fields
    $meta_query_array = ["relation" => "AND"];

    // final meta_query
    $query->set("meta_query", $meta_query_array);

    // used to conditionally build the tax_query
    // the tax_query is used for a custom taxonomy assigned to the post type
    // i'm using the `'relation' => 'OR'` to make the search more broad
    $tax_query_array = ["relation" => "OR"];

    // conditionally add arrays to the tax_query based on values in the URL
    // `organization` is the name of my custom taxonomy
    $category
      ? array_push($tax_query_array, [
        "taxonomy" => "organization",
        "field" => "term_id",
        "terms" => $category,
      ])
      : null;

      // Add search parameter for post title
    
      $query->set("s", $name);
    

    // final tax_query
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 12);
    $query->set('orderby', 'wpse_last_word');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    $query->set("tax_query", $tax_query_array);

    //TO DO - allow query to do name OR organization
    
  }
}
add_action("pre_get_posts", "researcher_archive");
```

archive-researcher.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Researcher Archive
 * Description: Custom template for displaying a list of researchers.
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">
        <section>

            <div class="container">
                <h1>Researchers</h1>
                <form method="GET" action="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link("researcher"); ?>">
                    <!-- gather data to use in form fields  -->
                    <?php
                        $categories = get_terms([
                        "taxonomy" => "organization",
                        "hide_empty" => false,
                        ]);
                    ?>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="r_name" id="r_name" placeholder="Search"
                            value="<?php echo get_query_var("r_name", false); ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <select name="organization" id="organization">
                            <option value="">Select a Organization</option>
                            <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>

                            <option id="<?php echo $category->name; ?>" value="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>"
                                <?php echo $category->slug == get_query_var("organization", false) ? "selected" : null; ?>>
                                <?php echo $category->name; ?>

                            </option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button>Search</button>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link("researcher"); ?>">Reset</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex">
                        <?php get_template_part('template/card', 'researcher'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <p>No researchers found.</p>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>

            </div>
        </section>

    </main>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Check if removing the GROUP BY clause from the query helps, as described here, https://www.kevinleary.net/blog/wp_query-search-tax-query-fix/